# Find element by class after append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have this code:

```
$('body').append("<div class='foo'></div>");
var test = $('.foo');
```

I can't find `foo`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/6jr8e49h/. Have you checked the console for errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: it works amazing https://jsfiddle.net/LL4Lanub/

Comment: I suppose it is time to wrap the code with `$(document).ready(function() { ...code... });`

Comment: @Regent you are right definetly OP didn't have document ready

Comment: If you create the element before you append it, you'd already have a reference to it

Comment: @JqueryKing and/or didn't include jQuery's script to page before this code :)

Comment: @stefan - \How you sure $(.foo) not find in the Dom

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried that before doing any conclusions.
The problem was just a wrong selector. I delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap into the Document ready function. You need to first find document is ready then do action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').append("<div class='foo'></div>");
  var test = $('.foo');
  //do something here
});
```